# How to run an app on Tizen easily?

Tags: samsung-mobile, tizen, tizen-native-app

In order to run a tizen application on a real device whether it be in the debug or release mode, do I necessarily have to register on Samsung's website? And also do I have to generate a certificate?

I don't want it to be complicated, I just to be able to run app on a Tizen real device, that's it. Can I avoid registering as a developer at Samsung website?

Comment: _"To build and debug projects, to run projects as applications on an Emulator, dynamic analyzer, or external devices, to create packages, or to launch applications, you must register an author certificate in the Tizen IDE."_ [(source)](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tools/common-tools/certificate-registration?langredirect=1). Whether that requires you to do some kind of online registration I don't know, but I would suggest just following the steps outlined in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, to run on non-rooted tizen device you need to register on samsung website to generate a device profile for your device.

Comment: @srkushwaha, is it for free?

Comment: @Alan - Yes its free.

Answer (score -2):

For running your applications on samsung commercial devices, you have to register on samsung website and take tizen commercial certificates.
And, although it is no difference to register on samsung web site, improved UX will be announced soon for reducing your effort on registering commercial certificates.

It can be summarized as follows:

- For developing with Emulator in Tizen SDK and Tizen Reference devices, you can do with certificates after making certificates in Tizen IDE without any account.
- Only for developing real samsung device, it is needed to register your account on samsung website.

Comment: so it's not for free?